# Infinity - infinity limit with no easy way to get rid of it

Tags: limits

I need to calculate this limit: $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt{x+1}-5\ln({x+1})$$

I've tried multiplying by $\frac{conjugate}{conjugate}$ but it makes for a pretty long calculation and I'm not sure about it.

So the question is: is my procedure OK, or did I reach the correct result by mere chance?

Is there a better path I could've chosen?

Here is my procedure, I omitted some simplification steps.

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} (\sqrt{x+1}-5\ln({x+1}))\frac{\sqrt{x+1}+5\ln({x+1})}{\sqrt{x+1}+5\ln({x+1})}
$$
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{({x+1})-25\ln^2({x+1})}{\sqrt{x+1}+5\ln({x+1})}
$$

At this point I still have ${\infty}-{\infty}$ on the numerator.

If I distribute the denominator accross both operands I get:

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{({x+1})}{\sqrt{x+1}+5\ln({x+1})}-\frac{25\ln^2({x+1})}{\sqrt{x+1}+5\ln({x+1})}
$$

Applying L'Hopital on the first term I get:

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+1}}+\frac{5}{x+1}}=+\infty
$$

On the second term I had a rough time but here's what I came up with:

First L'Hopital

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{-50\ln({x+1})2(x+1)^\frac{3}{2}}{(x+1)+10(x+1)^\frac{1}{2}}
$$

Then took $(x+1)^\frac{1}{2}$ factor on the denominator and simplified the expression as:

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{-100\ln({x+1})(x+1)}{10+(x+1)^\frac{1}{2}}
$$

It's still $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ so L'Hopital again:

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{-100-100\ln{(x+1)}}{2(x+1)^\frac{1}{2}}
$$

Ok, this is $\frac{-\infty}{\infty}$... L'Hopital again?

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{-100}{(x+1)(x+1)^\frac{1}{2}}=0
$$

If I didn't mess up, by limits algebra this is $+\infty-0=+\infty$

Which matches WolframAlpha's answer. Unfortunately it doesn't have a step-by-step for this particular limit.

Comment: You are working way too hard --

Answer (score 3):

Let $~\sqrt{x+1}=e^t.~$ Then the limit becomes $~\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\Big(e^t-10t\Big).~$ Can you take it from here ? ;-$)$

Comment: Oh, that's so elegant. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Alternatively**, if you know that
$$
\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{\log x}{\sqrt{x}}=0
$$ then you may just write your expression as
$$
 \sqrt{x+1}-5\ln({x+1})= \sqrt{x+1}\left(1-5\frac{\ln({x+1})}{\sqrt{x+1}}\right)\to \infty \times(1-0) = \infty.
$$

Comment: You are not answering his question, which was: "check my proof" :)

Comment: @uniquesolution actually, any suggestion to improve my process is more than welcome! :-)

Comment: @gnp  I am sure it is.